# Android NULL pointer Exception when trying to add a view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am 2 days old to Android Programming. I may be comitting a mistake at the core level. If this is the case, pardon.

I am trying to add a text box to a Relative Layout. When a button is clicked.
The method is bound to the button by the attribute `android:onClick="method"`

By doing the below.

```
public method (View view){
    RelativeLayout vRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.rLayout);
    TextView vET = new TextView(this);
    vET.setText("Text added to view.");
    vET.setId(1);
    vRL.addView(vET);
    setContentView(R.layout.rLayout);
}
```

But I am getting a null pointer exception at `vRL.addView(vET);`

- what is it that I am doing wrong? -OR-
- Am I not adding the `TextView` element properly?

Comment: which is main setContentView ?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya it is set to rLayoutHome. How to proceed the same with inflating a layout and adding an element.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.rLayout);
```

put this line in `onCreate()` of Activity..

and this line from `method()`

```
RelativeLayout vRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayout);
```

Comment: I am trying to change the contentview from one layout to another from an activity. I do not want to setthe view to `setContentView(R.layout.rLayout);` at the beginning.

Comment: Then you can not find R.id.rLayout RelativeLayout in your activity without setContentVIew() before. It always be null.

Answer (score 1):

in below line

```
RelativeLayout vRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.rLayout);
```

change the `R.layout.rLayout` to `R.id.rLayout`

Comment: yup it results in null but Why?

Comment: Because there is no any setContenView() in your Activity before accessing this RelativeLayout and findViewById() only works in there is any View inflated to Activity. Or you can inflated a View and access RelativeLayout by reference of this view...

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line with

```
`RelativeLayout vRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id."id name of relative layout");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like this:

```
public method (View view){
    RelativeLayout vRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayout);
    TextView vET = new TextView(this);
    vET.setText("Text added to view.");
    vET.setId(1);
    vRL.addView(vET);
    setContentView(R.layout.rLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the R.layout.rLayout to R.id.rLayoutR.layout.rLayout);